# How can I align text to the bottom?

Tags: react-native

Thank you in advance for the answers
I'm trying to align the text to the bottom of the box, How will I do that?
I have tried `textAlignVertical` but it does not work. Do you have any suggestions?

[Image of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iozyu.jpg)

I'm using styled components and this is a very simple text.

```
const Display_1 = styled.Text`
   font-size: ${Typography.FONT_SIZE_60}px // 49.379....px
   line-height: ${Typography.LINE_HEIGHT_53}px; //43.619....px
   letter-spacing: -1px;
   font-family: ${Typography.FONT_FAMILY_REGULAR} // Heebo
   font-weight: ${Typography.FONT_WEIGHT_REGULAR} // 400
`;


<Display_1>
   Display H1 - Left
</Display_1>
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Bottom of the screen?

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani  not bottom of the screen, Check the image. I want it at the bottom of the blue box so the whole text is showing.

Comment: @Anhdevit I have added the code

Comment: I did not create the blue box, I am inspecting element and the blue box is in selection

Answer (score 0):

Add these styles to your blue area of the text.

```
bottomText: {
  position: 'absolute',
  bottom: '0px'
}
```

Comment: No it didn't work. The blue box is not a box I created

I am inspecting element and the blue box is in selection

Comment: Could you please add the whole code where you are rendering this text component.

Comment: I have added it